# Code from jsfiddle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need a piece of code to use in my website (that I hardly found), but when I use it inside my html file, it doesn't work.

I tried placing it before `<html>` , in head and in body, doesn't work either way.
Also tried `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

I'm using:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js></script>
```

but maybe I need another one

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/.

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#two');
```

Comment: What is not working in above code and what is your goal?

Comment: Guess it has something to do with your css positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in the document ready function.  It's possible your javascript is erroring out because that ajax script is 404ing.  I just tested this code verbatim and it worked fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html{
    height:200%;
}


#one {
    width:100%;    
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: fixed;
}


#two {
    width: 100%;    
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:150%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windw = this;

    $.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(windw),
            $bumper = $(elem),
            bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
            thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
            setPosition = function(){
                if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                    });
                } else {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: 0
                    });
                }
            };
        $window.resize(function()
        {
            bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
            thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
            setPosition();
        });
        $window.scroll(setPosition);
        setPosition();
    };

    $('#one').followTo('#two');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">FIXED...</div>
    <div id="two">...BUT STOPS HERE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If it's still not working check the console in your browser, you may just have a random syntax error in your javascript somewhere.  Pasting this code into a file will demonstrate the same thing that jsfiddle is doing.

Comment: Copied and works, though when I add the document ready in my layout of code it doesn't work. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @DeneaNovac Check your console in the browser, chances are there's just a syntax error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

what you want same jsfiddle  work then it's working fine, if your using whatever code you provided here your missing quotes @second js file path, or if you want any thing else more than this fiddle can you mention here ...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the following code working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
       body, html{
        height:200%;
        }


        #one {
            width:100%;    
            height: 200px;
            background-color: aqua;
            position: fixed;
        }


        #two {
            width: 100%;    
            height:50px;
            background-color: red;
            margin-top:150%;
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">FIXED...</div>
    <div id="two">...BUT STOPS HERE</div>
    <script>
        var windw = this;

        $.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
            var $this = this,
                $window = $(windw),
                $bumper = $(elem),
                bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
                thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
                setPosition = function(){
                    if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                        $this.css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                        });
                    } else {
                        $this.css({
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: 0
                        });
                    }
                };
            $window.resize(function()
            {
                bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
                thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
                setPosition();
            });
            $window.scroll(setPosition);
            setPosition();
        };

        $('#one').followTo('#two');


    </script>
</body>
```